# How do I make RubyGems install binaries to a different directory?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ruby, rubygems

I'm on OS X (Snow Leopard) and all I want is for `gem` to put the binaries it installs into `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`. This doesn't seem like it should be hard, but my Google-Fu is failing me this morning. What's the switch and/or config setting to control this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `-n/--bindir` switch.